# How to animate the div from top to bottom ? Like a shooting star

Tags: html, css, css-animations

How can I animate this div element so it starts at the top and ends at the bottom and then disappears something like a shooting star effect?

Currently, this code is going from top to bottom but it returns from bottom to top(I do not want this effect), I will like to start always from top all the way to the bottom, any suggestion?

```
css

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.St {
  width: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  animation: animateDiv 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes animateDiv {
  0%   {bottom: 0px; top: 50px; }
}


html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<body>

<div>
<div class="St"></div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use `animation-fill-mode:forwards` which will end at the last frame. But you also need to better define your [keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) (*add 100%*), and finally it suits your case better to use [`position:fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed) instead of `relative`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.St {
  width: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  position: fixed;
  animation: animateDiv 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes animateDiv {
  0% {top:0;}
  100%{top:100%}
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="St"></div>
</div>
```